# Realtime Search and Replace

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a file which contains lots of numbers which I want to reduce to construct a new file. First, I extract all the text using `File.ReadAllText`, then I split and extract numbers from each line that contains a number which are separated by commas or spaces. After scan, I replace all occurrences of each found number with the new reduced number but the problem is that this method is error prone since some numbers get replaced more than once

Here's the code I'm using:

```
List<float> oPaths = new List<float>();
List<float> nPaths = new List<float>();
var far = File.ReadAllText("paths.js");
foreach(var s in far.Split('\n'))
{
    //if it starts with this that means there are some numbers
    if (s.StartsWith("\t\tpath:"))
    {
        var paths = s.Substring(10).Split(new[]{',', ' '});
        foreach(var n in paths)
        {
            float di;
            if(float.TryParse(n, out di))
            {
                if(oPaths.Contains(di)) break;
                oPaths.Add(di);
                nPaths.Add(di * 3/4);
            }
        }
    }
}

//second iteration to replace old numbers with new ones
var ns = far;
    for (int i = 0; i < oPaths.Count; i++)
    {
        var od = oPaths[i].ToString();
        var nd = nPaths[i].ToString();
        ns = ns.Replace(od, nd);
    }
    File.WriteAllText("npaths.js", ns);
```

As you can see, the above method is redundant as it does not replace the strings on real time. Maybe my head is full, but I'm just lost on how to go about this. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a regex can help here

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
string newtext = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b(([0-9]+)?\.)?[0-9]+\b", m =>
    {
        float f;
        if (float.TryParse(m.Value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f)) f *= 3.0f / 4;
        return f.ToString();
    });
File.WriteAllText(file, newtext);
```

Comment: Superb, faster than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just after typing the question I realized the answer was to iterate character by character and replace accordingly. Here's the code I used to get this to work:

```
string nfar = "";
var far = File.ReadAllText("paths.js");
bool neg = false;
string ccc = "";
for(int i = 0; i < far.Length; i++)
{
    char c = far[i];
    if (Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
    {
        ccc += c;
        if (far[i + 1] == ' ' || far[i + 1] == ',')
        {
            ccc = neg ? "-" + ccc : ccc;
            float di;
            if (float.TryParse(ccc, out di))
            {
                nfar += (di*0.75f).ToString();
                ccc = "";
                neg = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (c == '-')
    {
        neg = true;
    }
    else
    {
        nfar += c;
    }
}
File.WriteAllText("nfile.js", nfar);
```

Comments and/or optimization suggestions are welcome.